# KDE Splash Screen doesn't disappear

Tags: linux, kde, opensuse, desktop, desktop-environment

Whenever I boot OpenSUSE, The KDE splash screen appears, which is normal. What is not normal, however, is that it never disappears again ! The previous session's windows just appear. KDE is functioning absolutely normal, but this is really annoying, because I can't use the taskbar and I have to use Alt+F2 whenever I want to launch anything. This also makes me lose desktop features, like folders, wallpapers, the clock and themes.
I am using KDE 5.

What can I do to:

1. Make KDE start a new session every time, not just continue the previous one.
2. Make the splash screen disappear so that I can get my desktop again.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: same problem here with latest Arch Linux (also using Plasma 5)